# How do I get an input from an HTML textbox and store it in a variable in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

How do I post a value which is on the client-side and get it on the server-side.

example:

```
<form action="/myform" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="mytext" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

var express = require('express'); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express(); 
app.get('/myform', function(req, res){ 
    var myText = req.body.mytext; //mytext is the name of your input box
    res.send('Your Text:' +myText); 
}); 
app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:3000/myform" method="post">

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app     = express();

//Note that in version 4 of express, express.bodyParser() was
//deprecated in favor of a separate 'body-parser' module.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

//app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/myform', function(req, res) {
  var myText = req.body.mytext; //mytext is the name of your input box
    res.send('Your Text:' +myText); 
});
```

Comment: and the first mistake is you're setting get type request in your server side and in form you're making post type request make it app.post instead of app.get

Comment: I wanted to get the value on app.get for passing the value in query statement for cascading dropdown

Comment: you are contradicting basic concepts of HTTP, if you want to get in app.get then form method shouldn't be post and for your information if you want get data in req.body then your method must be post and for app.get you can get in  req.query or req.params and you have to pass data accordingly from client side. I hope you got my point

Comment: ok ill put in this way: I'm already getting the data from DB and pushing into  .ejs file to be specific into a dropdown, now using query I can get that selected value by using "on change" but how do I push it to the server-side of same app.get by which I would pass the value to query to change the result of next dropdown.

Comment: in simple words how do I get the value of a selected drop dropdown without using the post method and show it on the same page but on the server-side

Comment: get value at client side in vanilla JS and then send it via fetch with get type request  vanilla JS all in vanilla JS at client side are you getting my point.

Comment: something like using AJAX call will work to get a value if so how as the link below says but code doesn't work.https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-get-an-input-from-an-HTML-textbox-and-store-it-in-a-variable-in-Node-js

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine, apart from wrong method name. In HTML form you have mentioned `POST` method but at server you are listening to `GET` method. So just change, `app.get('/myform',` to `app.post('/myform',`.

It should work.